# How to calculate line-line distance when cross product of directions is 0?

Tags: geometry, vectors, 3d

I have the lines

$$\frac{x-1}{2} = 1-y = \frac{z-2}{3} \tag{1}$$

and

$$\frac{x+1}{4} = \frac{4-y}{2} = \frac{z+1}{6} \tag{2}$$

I want to compute the distance between them.

I started by putting them in vector form:

$$r_1 = (1,1,2) + x(2,-1,3) \tag{3}$$

and

$$r_2 = (-1,4,-1) + y(4,-2,6) \tag{4}$$

I then wanted to project a line connecting the two along the unit normal to both lines. However, when I computed the cross product of their directions, I get $(0,0,0)$. This led me to believe the distance between the lines is zero - which is not the case.

What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The distance you want is the shortest distance which is perpendicular to both lines. Take any point on the two lines in terms of any parameter you want to assign say $k_1$ and $k_2$ suppose points are $P_1:(f_1(k_1),f_2(k_1),f_3(k_1)$ on $L_1$ and  $P_2:(f_4(k_2),f_5(k_2),f_6(k_2)$ on $L_2$ . The direction cosine joining the two point, $P_2-P_1$ and if you find shortest distance these direction cosine should be perpendicular to both the lines. Solve for the variable $k_1$ and $k_2$ from these condition you got the points and thus the distance.

Comment: Is this not the same as what I was trying to do?

Comment: Ah i see now they are parallel lines!

Comment: or maybe coincident haven't checked that. I never tried vector cases I usually did my result in cartesian , I was more comfortable in that. But in case of parallel line simply take like any point on the line 1 you are most convenient with. Find a d.r perpendicular. Find the other point and you are done.

Comment: Maybe the perpendicular vector won't work because they are both parallel vector and hence you can't find any information by that, because the sum is zero. It can't tell you how far two vector are from each other. Only what is their relative angle or area enclosed by parallelogram and a normal unit vector.

Comment: It works. Consider $(r_1-r_2,(2,-1,3))=0$, then find $x(y)$ and substitute it back into $|r_1-r_2|$ so $y$ vanishes and you get the distance.

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin This results in (-6,0,4)=(0,0,0), making it impossible.

Comment: @Tedfoo: Ohh. I denote the dot product by $(r_1-r_2,(2,-1,3))$, not the cross product... What is the common way to denote a dot product?...

Comment: With a "." in between the vectors in vector notation(arrowhead).

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin OK. This works, but gives an answer different to that of wolfram alpha - sqrt(22) instead of wolfram's sqrt(26/7).

Comment: @Tedfoo: You can compare your solution against another answer, which gives $\sqrt{26/7}$ too :) To see what differs

Answer (score 0):

The most common way to calculate the distance **not** using the cross product is:
Let $\mathbf{r}_1=\mathbf{A}+x\mathbf{l}_1$, $\mathbf{r}_2=\mathbf{B}+y\mathbf{l}_2$ the lines and $(\mathbf{a},\mathbf{b})$ the inner(or the dot) product of $\mathbf{a},\mathbf{b}$.
(a) We find 2 points $\mathbf{r}_1, \mathbf{r}_2$ on the lines such, that $(\mathbf{r}_1-\mathbf{r}_2,\mathbf{l}_1)=0$ and $(\mathbf{r}_1-\mathbf{r}_2,\mathbf{l}_2)=0$ (i.e. $\mathbf{r}_1-\mathbf{r}_2$ perpendicular to both lines)
(b) then $|\mathbf{r}_1-\mathbf{r}_2|$ would be the distance.
However, if $\mathbf{l}_1||\mathbf{l}_2$, only one variable vanishes as the two equations above are equivalent, so you just substitute the other variable into $|\mathbf{r}_1-\mathbf{r}_2|$ and it vanish as the lines are parallel.
In the case above:
$\mathbf{r}_1=(1,1,2)+x(2,−1,3), \mathbf{r}_2=(−1,4,−1)+y(4,−2,6),$
$\mathbf{r}_1-\mathbf{r}_2=(2,-3,3)+(x-2y)(2,−1,3)$
$(\mathbf{r}_1-\mathbf{r}_2,\mathbf{l}_1)=((2,-3,3)+(x-2y)(2,−1,3),(2,−1,3))=$
$((2,-3,3),(2,−1,3))+(x-2y)((2,−1,3),(2,−1,3))=16+14(x-2y)=0$
$x-2y=-\frac{8}{7}$
$\mathbf{r}_1-\mathbf{r}_2 = (2,-3,3)-\frac{8}{7}(2,−1,3)=\left(-\frac{2}{7}, -\frac{13}{7}, -\frac{3}{7}\right)$
$|\mathbf{r}_1-\mathbf{r}_2|=\frac{\sqrt{2^2+13^2+3^2}}{7}=\frac{\sqrt{182}}{7}$